# SSIS REGEX CLEAN transformation error

Tags: regex, transformation, ssis

I have used RegexClean Transformation to clean my data

```
  match : [!@#$%^&*_+`{};':,./<>?0123456789](?<empty>)
  replace : ${empty}
```

It is removing the special characters but the only problem is it is giving me nulls for the rows which are correct So I am little confused why exactly is this error occuring

```
 NUM        VEH                 NAME             NAME_Clean
                1       CREDEUR CYNTHIA D        NULL
                2       FLUKE NANCY C            NULL
 017            1       CLARK, WILLIAM           CLARK WILLIAM
 037            2       DESORMEAUX, MICHELLE     DESORMEAUX MICHELLE
 043            1       FALCON, JENNIFER,        FALCON JENNIFER
 073            2       WINTERS, ALLEN           WINTERS ALLEN
 084            1       UNKNOWN                  NULL
 094            2       UNKNOWN                  NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My quick assumption is that since it's finding nothing to correct, it's returning NULL. If there isn't an option in the component for returning the source value, then you will need to add a Derived Column after the component and use some logic to create a NAME_final column with an expression like `ISNULL([NAME_Clean])?[NAME]:[NAME_Clean]` This specifies that if the NAME_Clean column contains NULL, then we should use the original value. Otherwise, use the non-null NAME_Clean.